# SQL Delete Query After 150 Minutes In Wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I try to delete posts where post contains "iframe" string and older than 150 minutes. However, it deletes all contents even added just 1 minutes ago. There is a problem with second condition of WHERE part. I couldn't solve it. Where is the problem, do you have any idea?

```
$delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content like '%iframe%' AND post_date_gmt < (NOW() - INTERVAL 150 MINUTE)");
```

[Screenshot of the wp_post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gyVk.png)

Comment: can you print the output of (NOW() - INTERVAL 150 MINUTE)

Comment: go figure it out to get the current datetime

Comment: Okey I checked again, post_date_gmt returns NOW() statement in format of "2017-05-24 20:44:03", it must run. But I don't know, event now. Why it doesn't work.

Comment: can you post your table structure? i want to see the post_date_gmt data type and data itself

Comment: Name: post_date_gmt  Type: datetime Null: NO Default: 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Should I put 0000-00-00 02:30:00 except 150 MINUTE

Comment: and your data which you want to delete?

Comment: For wp_posts, ID: 219535 post_author: 0 post_date: 2017-05-29 05:17:08  post_date_gmt: 2017-05-29 02:17:08. This is just an example of one record.

Comment: you are not helping yourself.. when i say post you update your case and post a screenshot of the requirement.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think that I am able to post screenshot. I'm going add it

Comment: what's your current date time or the server's date time?